# Python - UnicodeDecodeError work around

Tags: python, filereader

I am writing code to read the output files from some software (LS-DYNA), and I get this error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 277: 
character maps to <undefined>
```

for arbitrary files.

I have a workaround where I go open the file in Notepad++ and delete certain characters, but the number of files that need analysis are too large for manual work.

Is there any module that allows reading files of any encoding type?

Comment: read the file as a binary blob if you don't want to do text processing, otherwise you'll need to determine the encoding (or agree on an encoding with the producer of the file).

Comment: Is there a way to determine the encoding of a text file before opening it? In code I mean.

Comment: No. That is not possible. I would urge you to read Joel's piece on Unicode: https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/